# JSON and PHP Efficiency

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to return the **productID** if I supply an **id**. For example: If I supply the **id** 17879, how can I get php to return the **productID** 12550

What I have is below, but I figure there has to be a way to do it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

---

```
    $sub_type = 17879; #Could be any id
    $pid = 0;
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);
        foreach ($obj as $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                foreach ($val as $val) {
                    if (is_array($val)) {
                        foreach ($val as $val) {
                            if ($val['id'] == $sub_type)
$pid = $val['productID'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    echo $pid;
```

---

$url supplies the following JSON

---

```
{
"meta": {
    "time": "Thursday, September 24, 2015 7:43:53 PM",
    "statusCode": 200
},
"results": {
    "errors": [],
    "messages": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 17879,
            "productID": 12550,
            "name": " Bill of Rights 8.5x11 ",
            "description": "",
            "hasTemplate": true,
            "deliveredPrices": [
                {
                    "description": "FedEx Ground",
                    "price": 84.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-25T16:14:49.283"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx 3 Day",
                    "price": 164.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-25T16:14:49.283"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx 2 Day",
                    "price": 224.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-25T16:14:49.287"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx Overnight PM",
                    "price": 304.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-25T16:14:49.287"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 17880,
            "productID": 12558,
            "name": "Annual Client Survey 8.5x11 (5 pages)",
            "description": "",
            "hasTemplate": true,
            "deliveredPrices": [
                {
                    "description": "FedEx Ground",
                    "price": 84.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T13:34:01.933"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx 3 Day",
                    "price": 164.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T13:34:01.933"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx 2 Day",
                    "price": 224.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T13:34:01.937"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx Overnight PM",
                    "price": 304.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T13:34:01.937"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 17881,
            "productID": 12559,
            "name": "Estate Planning 8.5x11 ",
            "description": "",
            "hasTemplate": true,
            "deliveredPrices": [
                {
                    "description": "FedEx Ground",
                    "price": 84.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T14:19:09.29"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx 3 Day",
                    "price": 164.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T14:19:09.297"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx 2 Day",
                    "price": 224.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T14:19:09.307"
                },
                {
                    "description": "FedEx Overnight PM",
                    "price": 304.4,
                    "country": null,
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "created": "2015-02-26T14:19:09.317"
                }
            ]
        },
```

.......
You get the idea. It keeps going. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. narrowing it down a bit you could sort of jump right into the data array and go from there.

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$sub_type = 17879;
$pid = 0;

foreach($obj['results']['data'] as $data){
    if($data['id'] == $sub_type){
        $pid = $data['productID'];
        }
    }

echo $pid; //12550
```

Is this what you are looking for? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have decoded the JSON into an associative array called `$array`, build an array with `ID` mapped to `productID`:

```
$array = json_decode($url, true);
$results = array_column($array['results']['data'], 'productID', 'ID');
echo $results[17879]; //12550
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Comment: Nice! In this particular case PHP 5.4 is still in use. Although, thanks for the awesome future reference!